# Hibernate, возможно ли добавление комментариев к полям

Tags: java, база-данных, hibernate

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Собственно вот. Поля для комментарий есть, а их самих нет)
Возможно ли добавить это чрез hibernate?

Comment: Каким образом описываете поля? xml или аннотации?

Comment: @AlexChermenin аннотации

Comment: Можно попробовать как-то так: `@Column(columnDefinition=" INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'комментарий'")`, но зависит от конкретной используемой БД

Comment: @AlexChermenin да, спасибо. Работает!) Добавьте в ответ, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При использовании аннотации `@Column` можно добавить параметр `columnDefinition`, в значении которого можно помимо всего прочего указать и комментарий:

```
@Column(columnDefinition=" INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'комментарий'")
```

Однако, стоит отметить, что работоспособность данного метода зависит от конкретной используемой базы данных.

Answer (score 1):

В Hibernate нет такой возможности. Да и стандартный SQL её тоже не поддерживает. Видимо потому, что смысла в этом функционале немного.

Comment: Вы правы, но прикольно же...